# Android : widget size for all screen

Tags: android, widget, size

How can I create a widget with a good size for all android device ? My widget on Galaxy Nexus is at the center but on Galaxy Note is rigt or left not in center :-( How can resolve this problem ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> How can resolve this problem ?

The problem, presumably, is with the layout you are using for your app widget. You need to take into account that app widgets will slightly vary in size from device to device and design your layout accordingly (e.g., use `fill_parent` for width and height of root element).